# How can I generate a map like this?

Tags: c, algorithm, bitmap

[image]

I'm trying to make basic street maps for a game, in C.  Each block is represented by a 1 or 0 in an array.  In the image, 1 is white, and represents street.  Black is zero and represents a building block.  The street has to be one block wide everywhere, and you can get from any piece of street to any other piece of street.

I've tried a few quick algorithms but they don't give me variation like in the image.  One method I tried was to choose random horizontal and vertical lines, but then I get an uninteresting tartan-type plan.

I tried flipping random bits over the whole image, but then it's messy to verify if all street pieces are reachable, and fixing them if they are not.

My next best guess is to generate random line segments horizontally and vertically, instead of full lines, but then I'm pretty sure that still might generate isolated street pieces.

I could use a genetic algorithm to generate candidates, but I really don't want to go to that trouble if there's a far simpler solution.

Is there an obvious solution I'm not thinking of?  The solution should be able to generate the given image, as well as other variations.

Comment: Is it a requirement that the buildings are rectangular?

Comment: No it's not a requirement, so long as the rules above still apply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Start with a queue with one rectangle in it, the whole map.
- Loop: Take a rectangle from the queue.

  - If the rectangle is small enough, then (with some probability) do nothing and you are done with that rectangle.
  - Otherwise, pick a long side. Cut that side with a street (modify the array) and add the rectangles on either side to the queue.

There is some flexibility when you decide whether a rectangle is small enough, and how you decide where to cut a rectangle. You can avoid leaving 1x1 squares by not cutting 4x1 or smaller rectangles. You could let there be a chance you keep a 3x5 rectangle, and a chance you cut it.

Comment: It is possible to create the image above with this algorithm if I change the rule "pick a long side" to "pick any side longer than three".  So that's good.

Answer (score 2):

Create the map by drawing a building in say the upper-lefthand corner. That defines two streets and recurse and build the rest of the map that way.

As a concrete example, let's go with your example where you have a 13x9 grid.

Starting at (1,1) randomly select a building size. Let's say as in your example, I get a 4x2 building. Ok. So now I add streets around that. Then I recurse and create maps for the 4x6 region to the right of that and the region 8x9 grid below. So at first I have:

```
xx 111111
xx 111111
xx 111111
xx 111111

222222222
222222222
222222222
...
```

Where "`x`" marks the location of a building, "" a street. "1" is one region I still need to make a map for. "2" is another region I need to make a map for.

Now let's work on the 4x6 region marked with 1's to the right. At its (1,1) position of that region or absolute position (1,4). I select a 1x2 building randomly. So now after putting a street around that I'd have:

```
xx xx 3333
xx    3333
xx 44 3333
xx 44 3333

2222222222
2222222222
2222222222
....
```

And so on. Note that the 2x2 region 4, subdividing further will add a street on added to another street. If you don't want this, then don't subdivide once you get to a region that is 2 or less.

Comment: This is the best answer so far, but I did notice that the above image can't be made using this algorithm.  Almost though.  The bottom left building ends up being a 3x4 block, rather than a 3x5 block.

Comment: One could amend this with what I think of as a "kink" peephole optimization. Along "long" streets which only occur at the beginning levels of recursion you could decide to add a bend in the street or not. This would be done after the recursion. I can amend the answer to include this there's interested. Other things I had considered but not mentioned for brevity was weighting the random building dimensions toward medium length, or deciding whether there should be a limit on building size either in a single dimension or in areas. Deciding if the edges should be considered a street or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for isolated street peaces, for example, by using DFS (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search). Then, you could connect those pieces by connecting two closest(or any other) points by making segments towards each point.